# Authenticating users to foursquare api using angular 4

Tags: angular, foursquare

I have been working on a restaurant finder application using angular 4 framework and foursquare api as the backend. I had been making userless requests to foursquare till now. Now I want to add authentication in my application. I tried reading the foursquare api documentation, but I couldn't understand how to form the url request for login to obtain the access token.

Could someone guide me to find angular libraries that supports authenticating users to foursquare or any useful tutorial?

Comment: Foursquare uses the popular Oauth 2.0 protocol - any Oauth 2.0 library should work for Foursquare authentication.

Comment: There are options for php, nodeJS, android, IOS. But none for angular2.